# Android 2D Game Animation

Tags: android, xml

I want to create a moving road for an Android 2D Game App (like GTA 1 or 2). For this task I want to line up multiple pictures. I have a picture of a road in my main.xml File and want to use it multiple times. But following code does not work:

```java
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ImageView road1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.road);
    ImageView road2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.road);

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -200.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    animation.setRepeatCount(0);
    animation.setRepeatMode(1);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);  

    road1.startAnimation(animation);
    road2.setX(road1.getX() + 500);
    road2.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

The idea is that both roads should move simultaneously and `road2` is the same as `road1` but moved 500 pixels to the right. I want to use a lot of different instances of the same road to create a map. I want to have one kind of a road only once in my main.xml file.

The problem with the code above is, that only the second road is shown on the screen. The reason is probably that the ImageViews `road1` and `road2` are using the same xml id reference.

I also tried Canvas, Drawables and Bitmaps. But they have no animation method.

How can I animate a map of roads? Should I insert every road part in my main.xml? How can I use the same picture multiple times?

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid game engines? There are some 2d engines out there that make tile based games way easier to make

Comment: No there is no reason. I will try out 2d engine unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you're going about the problem wrong.

I'll put aside the question of whether or not you should be trying to implement a 2D game using basic `Views` (short answer: probably not), and try to address what's wrong with your code.

Right now, you are creating 2 references in your code: `road1` & `road2`, but both these references reference the same `ImageView` defined in your XML layout with the id "`road`". So basically, you have 2 references to the same object.

When you animate `road1`, you're actually animating `road`, and then when you animate `road2`, you're again animating `road`. If you want to create 2 separate "`road`" views, you'll need to define them both in your layout file by creating 2 `ImageViews` and by giving them different IDs.

You pointed out that you don't want to do this because you want them to have the same background image. For this, you'll want to create 2 `ImageViews` in your XML layout, but have them both use the same `drawable` as a `src` or `background`.

Here is an example to illustrate the correction you need to make:

```
ImageView road1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.road1);
ImageView road2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.road2);
```

This correction assumes you have 2 `ImageViews` in your XML layout file - one named "`road1`", the other named "`road2`"

Again, if your goal is create a 2D game, I would suggest against this approach all together and perhaps looking some game engines such as Unity, or at the very least, implement your visual logic using OpenGL.